# AVAssetExportSession very slow while the cpu is idle

Tags: objective-c, avassetexportsession

I need to apply some operations after recording a video with `UIImagePickerController` :

- applying the trim the user chose
- converting it to MP4
- rotating the video if it has been recorded with the iPad upside/down

I use AVAssetExportSession for that, but even if I do not trim, do not rotate and convert to either MP4 or QT (which is input format), the export on a 720p video is very long (e.g. 50s for 80s of video on an iPad3).

I though first it was a cpu-intensive operation, but if I profile the app, the CPU is only active during the beginning of the first second and then is idle for a long time. If I launch activity monitoring, I have `mediaserverd` using 40%.

Do you think it is a normal duration for such a process ? Am I doing something wrong ? The "Photos" app captures and trim long videos in less than 1 sec...

```
AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:tempMediaURL options:nil];

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]   initWithAsset:videoAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPreset1280x720];
exportSession.outputURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForInterviewWithFileName:newFileName];
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are not dependent upon it being 720p try

```
presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
```

you'll notice a significant decrease in the processing time as scaling can be an expensive operation. Also in your

```
AVMutableCompositionTrack
```

you should specify the trim zone using the following

```
[yourCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:someDurationAsaCMTime ofTrack:videoAVAssetTrack atTime:theInsertTimeasCMTime error:&someError];
```

the processing time should then decrease as effectively it won't have to do a transcode.

What are you using to transform the video from upsidedown->not-upsidedown?

Comment: Capture is in 720p (and must be in output), so if I do not not put AVAssetExportPreset1280x720 as presets, it fails.

Comment: Ok, I will try the trim parameter, but the gain will only be when I am trimming. To rotate the video (which is not the cause of slowness as it is as slow when I'm not rotating), I am applying a transform as a videoComposition.